# Check if user already visited this post today

Tags: php, cookies, post-meta

I have a piece of code which measures a post popularity. How would I go about checking if user didn't already visited this post for past 24 hours? Do I need to set a cookie for user and for each post they visited? I

```
$count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'popular_posts', true);
    if(user-didnt-visited-this-page-in-last-24-hours) : 
       $count++;
       update_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, $count);
    endif;
```

Comment: Are these users logged in or they are just regular site visitors?

Comment: regular visitors

Comment: Then you can just use Cookies. Post Meta will crack as you might have more than one concurrent visitor.

Comment: Use @MaxYudin's answer below, but don't store the count in the cookie, instead, store the IP address `getHostByName(getHostName())` and then check for it in the list.. I mean, how would you tell the user from an int of counts? If you want an answer I would compose one. Also [this tutorial](http://blog.samelh.com/2016/03/08/how-to-get-and-update-post-views-count-and-stats-with-visitors-ip-addresses/) could help

Comment: @SamuelElh I'm interested in an answer from you on this approach.

Comment: @SamuelElh I tried tutorial, it works somehow but I am not sure what are cons & pros for storing IP address? This way a lot of IP addresses will be stored in database for no reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note! This code was not tested!

```
<?php
function my_visitor_cookie($post_id) {

    if ( empty($post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }

    // get post meta
    $count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'unique_post_visits', true);

    // if there was no meta value
    if( empty($count) ) {
        $count = 0;
    }

    // check if cookie was already set (cookie name for the current post)
    if( !isset($_COOKIE['my_visitor_' . $post_id]) ) {
        // set visitor cookie if it is not set already
        setcookie(
            'my_visitor_' . $post_id, // cookie name for the current post
            $post_id, // any value, shot in the dark
            DAY_IN_SECONDS // WordPress time constant
        );
        // increase count
        $count++;
        // update count
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'unique_post_visits', $count);
    }
}

// add_action('wp_head', 'my_visitor_cookie');
add_action('init', 'my_visitor_cookie'); // updated according to the comments
```

Comment: This would work if setcookie() would not trigger "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\site\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:237)". If I disable Yoast SEO then it magically works hm...

Comment: `wp_head` is too late to set cookie it can be `wp` for safer side ?

Comment: Hooking into `wp` or `init` should fix the header issues.

Comment: @SamuelElh @Sumit Yes, you are right both. I've updated the answer. I prefer `init` action because I'm more familiar with.

Comment: @MaxYudin You will not get post ID on `init` hook ;) `wp` is latest hook before cookie is sent!